# close gui window after progress bar finishes loading

Tags: for-loop, javafx, progress-bar, try-catch

I am new to java programming and I had a question with a problem I am having.

The code I currently have in place (that works) is loading the progress bar...but I would like the loading window to close upon progress bar completion [similar effect to a standalone program]

the name of my stage is called welcome
the progressbar is called load

here is my code:

```
final SimpleDoubleProperty prop = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

    load.progressProperty().bind(prop);
    load.prefWidthProperty().bind(start.widthProperty());

    new Thread(){
 @Override
 public void run(){                
      try {

           for(double i=0; i<=1; i+=0.01){
                prop.set(i); 
                Thread.sleep(100);

           }                   




      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           System.err.println("Error on Thread Sleep");

    }



 }
```

}.start();

I tried in many areas of the code block to include either welcome.hide() or welcome.close() after the for loop block and the try-catch block.

any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Use a [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) instead of Thread. Then you can put you `windows.close()` inside [setOnSucceeded()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-)

Answer (score 0):

One fast solution is using `Platform.runLater`:

Way 1 (Not Recommended):

```
new Thread(){
  @Override
  public void run(){                
      try {

           for(double i=0; i<=1; i+=0.01){           
              Platform.runLater( ()-> prop.set(i) );
              Thread.sleep(100);  
           }      

         Platform.runLater( ()-> window.close() );             

      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           System.err.println("Error on Thread Sleep");

    }

 }
```

---

**Why is that hapening?**

> Cause you are modifying the SceneGraph from External Thread and JavaFX
>   doesn't allow that.

---

Way 2) Correct way in JavaFX

**What is the best way i can do it?**

The best way you can do it is using a `Service`+`Task`[(+)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) so you can bind your `ProgressBar` `progressProperty` on the `Service` `progressProperty` . As soon as the `Service` ends or reaches the progress that you want you can close the `Stage`. The choices are unlimited here and that is the proper way to do it in `JavaFX`.

> Also and here you have to use `Platform.runLater` when you are
>   modifying `SceneGraph`

Example skeleton of a `Service`:

```
public class CustomService extends Service<Void> {

      public CustomService(){

      }

     @Override
     public void start(){

        super.start();
       //your code..

     }

     @Override
     public void stop(){

       super.stop();
       //your code...

     }


       @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {


               }
               return null;
            }
        }

   }
```

Comment: Note that you can't do `prop.set(...)` on the background thread, since the progress bar's `progressProperty()` is bounds to it (so changing it changes the UI).

Comment: James_D Hello James_D  I can't catch what you mean ? With the Service he/she doesn't need the `prop` variable . Or if he/she does use it why he/she can't change it inside the Service[Thread]?

Comment: I was referring to your first block of code, which still has `prop.set(...)` inside the `run()` method. That will throw an `IllegalStateException` (not on FX Application Thread), because it will cause the progress bar to update (because the OP has `load.progressProperty().bind(prop)`).

Comment: @James_D Oh i didn't saw it... yes it has to be inside a `Platform.runLater()...` i will fix it . Although i just added it just as a hotfix and not recommended the OP to use it.

Comment: @James_D I have one question here . Will the `prop.set(...)` work without a `Platform.runLater()...` inside The `Task` of `Service` ?

Comment: No. If a property of a UI control is bound to it, you cannot change it from a background thread. It makes no difference how you are organizing the threads (using a runnable or a task).

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really appreciate the help! :) @GOXR3PLUS